# What are macOS's security unlock-keychain's `-u` and `-h` option for?

Tags: macos, monterey

**Context**

Writing a script to unlock a macOS user's keychain. In `man security`, one can read without further details:

```
 unlock-keychain [-hu] [-p password] [keychain] Unlock keychain, or the default keychain if none is specified.
```

**Question**

What is the `-u` option for ?

OS: macOS Monterey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
security unlock-keychain -h
Usage: unlock-keychain [-u] [-p password] [keychain]
    -p  Use "password" as the password to unlock the keychain
    -u  Do not use the password
Use of the -p option is insecure
        Unlock the specified keychain.
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain what this is doing and how precisely it answers the question asked?

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it would be beneficial to cite *where* you obtained this info (like the man page) to help the OP build their knowledge

Comment: The OP already is aware of the man page, so answers should do more than just copy/paste the help text. What does "Do not use the password" mean in practice?

Comment: That isn't from the man page. It's the output of the command on the first line, which does indeed answer the question. I don't think it's necessary to insult the OP's intelligence by pointing that out.

Comment: I looked the man page only, out of habits and usually to get more details. Years of man page lookup can do this to you sometimes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 
@LincD did answer the question and provided the source (```security ..... -h```)

macOS Monterey man page for security is lacking and I should have check `--help`.